# Mottled yellow leaves on Zucchini [pictures] - Disease ID?

Tags: vegetables, diseases, squash, zucchini

I have some black beauty zucchini growing. I've noticed some leaves with a mottled orange/yellow color. It's not the whole plant but just some leaves. Other zucchinis in my garden of a different variety do not have this. Any thoughts as to what the issue is? Doesn't look like powderly mildew. If I had to guess, I'd say either a virus or nutrient deficiency.

[image]